# How does apache execute files without execute permission?

Tags: permissions, apache-2.4, fedora

This is how my code file permissions are set up:

```
groups apache
> apache : apache www

groups user1
> user1 : user1 wheel www
```

Meaning there is a dedicated group for `apache` and `user1`. Permissions on `/var/www` are `2775` and the owner is `user1:www`, meaning all sub files and sub folders will be in `www` group.

Now what I want to know is why `apache` is able to execute `.php` file even when they have `664` permissions?

System I am on is Fedora.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP files are processed by a PHP interpreter, which is typically a web server module, but may also be a standalone executable. This doesn't require execute permissions, as it only needs to read the script to interpret it.

Comment: Do execute permissions affect system users only?

Comment: @gskema the execute permission bit needs to be set when you instruct the OS to execute a file. If you have an executable bash script `runme.sh` you can do `./runme.sh`. If it's not executable, you can start it with `bash ./runme.sh`, because `bash` is exutable.

Comment: Or, for a php script, `php somephpfile.php`.